# Как узнать сумму значений при связях в моделях

Tags: yii2

есть модели `Goods` и `Rating` связаны они так

```
public function getRatings(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::className(),['id_gods'=>'id']);
    }
```

могу ли я узнать сумму поля `quantity` и общее количество записей и как это можно узнать ?

Comment: Что еще за поле `quantity`? В какой модели оно содержится? Общее количество каких записей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простым запросом,

```
$data = Rating::find()->where(['id_gods' => 'id'])->sum('quantity')
```

Или если нужно в другой связанной таблице , то

```
$data = Rating::find()->innerJoin('goods', 'rating.id_gods = goods.id')......
```

Читайте документацию https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/

Comment: не то, совсем не то спрашивал. есть две модели Goods и Rating они связаны всю инфу я беру жадной загрузкой как мне потом в представлении увидеть count или sum

Comment: count или sum чего?

Comment: ну пусть `count` будет поле  `id_gods`, а `sum` поле `quantity`

Comment: А в каких таблицах?